# Bedeutung von "einen auf interessiert machen"

Tags: phrase

> Von 7:45 Uhr bis 17 Uhr muss ich fast durchgängig in dunklen Klassenzimmern hocken und vor dem genauso lustlos wirkenden Lehrer **einen auf interessiert machen**.

Was ich aus dem Kontext erschließen kann, ist lediglich, dass der Schüler versucht, interessiert zu wirken. Stimmt das? Und ist das eine Redewendung?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du hast das schon richtig erkannt - der Schüler versucht `... vor dem genauso lustlos wirkenden Lehrer interessiert zu wirken.`

`... einen auf interessiert machen` sehe ich nicht als feststehende Redewendung in Hochdeutsch, sondern eher als Umgangssprache. Es drückt das geschauspielerte Interesse im Sinne der Lustlosigkeit allerdings umgangssprachlich treffender als beim Hochdeutsch aus.

Comment: Eine Redewendung ist es schon, nur eben eine umgangsprachliche ;) *Einen auf ... machen* kann in verschiedenen Zusammenhängen vorkommen, z.B. *Einen auf dicke Hose machen* = angeben, protzen, so tun, als ob man viel Geld hätte.